# MySQL combining queries/ subtracting 1 from the other

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot, average

Hi in MySQL I'm trying to get the avg salary difference between female account reps that work at a headquarters and female account reps that do not work at headquarters.

I've tried a few different things but I can't figure it out. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT avg(employees.salaries)
FROM employees
inner join location
on employees.location = location.location
WHERE gender = 'F' AND title = 'account rep'
```

Table 1: employees

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------+----------+
|  ID  | LastName  | FirstName |  Location   |    Title    | Gender | salaries |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------+----------+
| 1100 | Johnson   | James     | Chicago     | Account Rep | M      |     2000 |
| 1200 | Smith     | Sam       | Chicago     | Account Rep | M      |     3000 |
| 1300 | Mage      | Sydney    | Boston      | Account Rep | F      |     4000 |
| 1400 | Engl      | Beth      | Dallas      | Account Rep | F      |     2500 |
| 1500 | Ali       | Tyler     | Miami       | Account Rep | M      |     3500 |
| 1600 | Rubin     | Patricia  | Los Angeles | Account Rep | F      |     4400 |
| 1700 | Childress | Rubin     | Los Angeles | Account Rep | M      |     1500 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+--------+----------+
```

table 2: location

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------+
|  Location   | Headquarters   |      Code |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| Dallas      | No             |        12 |
| Los Angeles | Yes            |        10 |
| Chicago     | No             |        11 |
| Denver      | Yes            |        10 |
| Miami       | Yes            |        10 |
+-------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is quite there. You just need conditional logic in aggregate functions:

```
select
    avg(case when l.headquarters = 'Yes' then salaries end)
    - avg(case when l.headquarters = 'No' then salaries end) avg_diff
from employees e
inner join locations l on l.location = e.location
where e.gender = 'F' and e.title = 'Account Rep'
```